# Custom merge rows in LaTeX

Tags: tables, latex3

I need to create a table as seen in the image, but the text does not fit.

[image]

This is how it looks:

[image]

The code used:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}| p{11cm}|}
\hline Versiones compatibles & Particularidades \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{4cm}{Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 N} & \\
& \multirow{2}{11cm}{Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 y 2022:
- Versión x86 para un sistema operativo de 32 bits (necesaria para el control de origen SVN y GIT),
- Versión x64 para un sistema operativo de 64 bits (necesaria para el control de origen GIT)}. \\ \cline{1-1}
\multirow{2}{4cm}{Windows 10 Windows 10 N} & \\
& \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{TablaRequisitosSoftware} Requisitos de software.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the rows using `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}` and vertically center the multirow using the optional parameter.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \sffamily\small
            \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                \hline Versiones compatibles & Particularidades \\ \hline
                Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 N & \\
                & \multirow{2}{9cm}[3.5ex]{Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 y 2022: \\
                    - Versión x86 para un sistema operativo de 32 bits (necesaria para el control de origen SVN y GIT),\\
                    - Versión x64 para un sistema operativo de 64 bits (necesaria para el control de origen GIT)} \\ \cline{1-1}
            Windows 10 Windows 10 N & \\
                & \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{\label{TablaRequisitosSoftware} Requisitos de software.}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

  \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, vspan=even, colspec={ l X }}
   Versiones compatibles & Particularidades \\
    \SetCell{valign=m} Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 N & \SetCell[r=2]{l} {Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 y 2022: \\
     - Versión x86 para un sistema operativo de 32 bits (necesaria para el control de origen SVN y GIT),\\
- Versión x64 para un sistema operativo de 64 bits (necesaria para el control de origen GIT).} \\
    Windows 10 Windows 10 N &
  \\
  \end{tblr}

\caption{Requisitos de software.}
\label{TablaRequisitosSoftware} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newbox\scratchbox
\newcommand\scratchboxwidth{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\par\null\hfill
\hbox{%
  \setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{%
    \hbox{Versiones compatibles}%
    \hbox{Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 N}%
    \hbox{Windows 10 Windows 10 N}%
  }%
  \edef\scratchboxwidth{\the\wd\scratchbox}%
  \setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr\textwidth-\scratchboxwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax
    \linewidth=\hsize
    \noindent
    \strut Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 y 2022:
    \expandafter\def\csname @list\romannumeral\the\numexpr\csname @listdepth\endcsname+1\relax\endcsname{%
      \parsep=0pt %
      \topsep=0pt %
      \itemsep=0pt %
      \settowidth\labelwidth{\hbox{\csname labelitem\romannumeral\the\csname @listdepth\endcsname\endcsname}}%
      \leftmargin=\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \itemindent=0pt
      \csname @list@extra\endcsname
    }%
    \begin{itemize}%
    \item Versión x86 para un sistema operativo de 32 bits (necesaria para el control de origen SVN y GIT),%
    \item Versión x64 para un sistema operativo de 64 bits (necesaria para el control de origen GIT).\strut
    \end{itemize}%
  }%
  \vrule width \arrayrulewidth
  \vtop{%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
    \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut Versiones compatibles\vphantom{Particularidades}\kern\tabcolsep}%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
    \vbox to\dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox\relax{%
      \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\rlap{\strut Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 N}\kern\scratchboxwidth\kern\tabcolsep}%
      \vfill
      \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
      \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut Windows 10 Windows 10 N}%
      \vfill
    }%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
  }%
  \vrule  width \arrayrulewidth
  \vtop{%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
    \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut Particularidades\vphantom{Versiones compatibles}\kern\tabcolsep}%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
    \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\box\scratchbox\kern\tabcolsep}%
    \hrule height \arrayrulewidth
  }%
  \vrule  width \arrayrulewidth
}\hfill\null\par
\caption{Requisitos de software.}\label{TablaRequisitosSoftware}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]